# context.createDatabase is not finding in preferences DataStore Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack-datastore

I've just implemented Preferences by Android DataStore
but I can't find  "context.createDataStore"
I added this dependency below

> implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0"

and also I did clean and Rebuild Project
but I can't find createDataStore function

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and, I think that `context.createDatastore` isn't yet in this version
I tried with this dependency version

```
"androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0-alpha01"
```

and it worked for me but be careful this version is not yet stable.

Answer (score 2):

I used this version and solved the problem:

```
androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0
```

I was using this version before:

```
androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences-core:1.0.0
```